# Opening and Closing Inventory between Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have four tables

1. tblDate (Date, Year, Month, Day)
2. tblItems (ItemID, ItemName)
3. tblItemReceived (Date, ItemID, Quantity)
4. tblItemUsed (Date, ItemID, Quantity)

I want report with:

```
Date, ItemName, Opening Quantity, Received Quantity, Used Quantity, Balance
```

I cannot get the results in date when no receiving.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cGZU.jpg)

[image]

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ8h9.jpg)

[image]

i applied, with different table (original)

```
select *
FROM (SELECT ivt.ITEMID AS rItemID, ivt.NAMEALIAS as rItemName, iUOM, YearRec, MonthRec, OpeningStock, RecMaterial 
    FROM INVENTTABLE ivt LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT in1.YearRec, in1.MonthRec, in1.rItemID, iUOM, ISNULL(in1.OpeningStock, 0) AS OpeningStock, ISNULL(in1.ReceivedMaterial,0) AS RecMaterial
          FROM (SELECT Year(ReceivedDate) AS YearRec, Month(ReceivedDate) AS MonthRec, rItemID, iUOM, MIN(OpenQty) AS OpeningStock, SUM(RecQty) ReceivedMaterial
                FROM (  SELECT rItemID, ReceivedDate, iUOM,  SUM(ReceivedQty) AS RecQty, (SELECT SUM(q.QTY) FROM VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS q WHERE q.INVENTDATE < rm.ReceivedDate AND q.ITEMID = rm.rItemID) AS OpenQty
                        FROM (  SELECT vp.ITEMID AS rItemID, vp.INVENTDATE as ReceivedDate, vp.PURCHUNIT as iUOM, SUM(vp.QTY) as ReceivedQty FROM VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS AS vp GROUP BY vp.ITEMID, vp.INVENTDATE,vp.PURCHUNIT) rm
                GROUP BY rItemID, ReceivedDate,iUOM) inv
           GROUP BY Year(ReceivedDate), Month(ReceivedDate), rItemID, iUOM) in1 WHERE (in1.YearRec= 2016 AND in1.MonthRec = 06)
           ) iv2 
        ON ivt.ITEMID = iv2.rITemID) le
LEFT JOIN                    
    (SELECT c1.YearConsume, c1.MonthConsume, c1.cItemID, c1.BOM_Unit, MIN(c1.BOM_Consumption_Prev) as PrevConsump, SUM(c1.BOM_ConsumptionQty_Curr) AS TotalConsump
        FROM (  SELECT Year(DateConsume) AS YearConsume, Month(DateConsume) AS MonthConsume, ItemID as cITemID, BOM_Unit, ISNULL(BOM_Consumption_Open,0) AS BOM_Consumption_Prev, SUM(BOM_ConsumptionQty) AS BOM_ConsumptionQty_Curr
            FROM (  SELECT DateConsume, ItemID, BOM_Unit, SUM(BOM_Consumption) AS BOM_ConsumptionQty,
                    (   SELECT SUM(bc.BOM_Consumption) FROM (SELECT (b.TRANSDATE) AS DateConsume, b.ITEMID AS cItemID, b.BOMUNITID BOM_Unit, SUM(b.BOMCONSUMP) AS BOM_Consumption FROM PRODJOURNALBOM b GROUP BY b.TRANSDATE, b.ITEMID, b.BOMUNITID) bc
                        WHERE (bc.DateConsume < aa.DateConsume) AND bc.cItemID = aa.ItemID) AS BOM_Consumption_Open
                    FROM (SELECT (b.TRANSDATE) AS DateConsume, b.ITEMID AS ItemID, b.BOMUNITID BOM_Unit, SUM(b.BOMCONSUMP) AS BOM_Consumption FROM PRODJOURNALBOM b GROUP BY b.TRANSDATE, b.ITEMID, b.BOMUNITID) aa
                    GROUP BY DateConsume, ItemID, BOM_Unit) cc
            GROUP BY Year(DateConsume), Month(DateConsume), ItemID,BOM_Unit, BOM_Consumption_Open) c1 
        WHERE  (YearConsume= 2016 AND MonthConsume = 06) 
        GROUP BY c1.YearConsume, c1.MonthConsume, c1.cItemID, c1.BOM_Unit) rt
ON le.rItemID = rt.cITemID
WHERE le.rITEMID IN ('FML-RM006', 'FML-RM008','FML-RM016','FML-RM018')
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: I cannot get the result of 02-Jun-16 and 04-Jun-16.

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: OK, original tables are different, its very long query i applied. i just simplified for better help from you.

Comment: Did you try to put the date table as first table in your query and left join all other tables to it? This should help getting records for Dates without "receiving" / "using" records...

Comment: i could not get results...